# How to distribute a bulk Order Amount equally into the service tenure months

Tags: postgresql

I have input table where the Order amount is paid in bulk ( refer Order Amount column ). I need to divide this bulk amount equally based on the number of months from Start Date to End Date.

[Click here for Input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5l7f.png)

This is my expected result where for every order id the amount is equally split into number of months from start date to end date

[Click here for expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9BRT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking it down into a few steps:

- First we need the number of months the payment is spread out over

  `extract(year from end_date-start_date)*12+extract(month from end_date-start_date) as order_length`
- We now know the amount for each month is `order_amount/order_length`
- Next it depends what other tables you have access to - if you don't already have a calendar table they come in handy so I recommend making one [this will walk you through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821915/calendar-tables-in-postgresql-9)
- Join your calendar table on where the month in the table is between the start and end dates in your order
- You can then use the crosstab function to pivot on the month from your calendar table to get months across the top and order numbers along the side

Comment: Hi @Lio Elbammaf thanks for taking time to answer. But can you explain it in details as I am pretty new to this

Comment: @ManojPr Which part are you stuck on and what have you written so far?

Comment: Elbammaf I don't know how to proceed with these Steps 
- Join your calendar table on where the month in the table is between the start and end dates in your order 
- You can then use the crosstab function to pivot on the month from your calendar table to get months across the top and order numbers along the side

Comment: I created a table with these queries, please guide me through:

create table orders ( order_month date, order_id text, order_amount int, start_date date, end_date date)


INSERT INTO orders values ('2022-01-01','order1', 3000, '2022-01-01', '2022-03-31'),
                                            ('2022-01-01','order2', 6000, '2022-01-01', '2022-06-30'),
                ('2022-02-01','order3', 4000, '2022-02-01', '2022-05-31'),
               ('2022-02-01','order4', 1000, '2022-02-01', '2022-03-31');

Comment: @ManojPr You also need to create a calendar table - an example is linked in my answer. To join you want to so something like select * from orders o left join calendar c on c.date>=o.start_date and c.date<=o.end_date

Comment: Elbammaf thank you for guiding me. It worked like a charm. Means a lottt